# Conditional operator doesn't work with two types that inherit the same base type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, conditional-operator

How come the conditional operator (`?:`) doesn't work when used with two types that inherit from a single base type?

The example I have is:

```
ActionResult foo = (someCondition)? 
                      RedirectToAction("Foo","Bar") :
                      Redirect(someUrl);
```

Where the long form works fine:

```
ActionResult foo;

if(someCondition)
{
  foo = RedirectToAction("Foo","Bar");
}
else
{
  foo = Redirect(someUrl);
}
```

Both return types, `RedirectToRouteResult`  and `RedirectResult`, inherit from `ActionResult`.

Comment: try casting to base type: (e.g: ActionResult foo = (someCondition)? 
                      (ActionResult ) RedirectToAction("Foo","Bar") :
                      (ActionResult ) Redirect(someUrl);
 )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How come the conditional operator (?:) doesn't work when used with two types that inherit from a single base type?

The type of the conditional expression has to be *either* the type of the second operand *or* the type of the third operand, as per the language specification. The compiler doesn't try to find a common base type, or another type that both operands can be converted to. The *use* of the expression doesn't affect how its type is determined - so the variable assignment is irrelevant here.

As for *why* the language is defined like this - it makes it considerably simpler to specify, implement, test and predict. This is fairly common in language design - keeping the language simple is usually a better bet in the long run, even if it makes it slightly more awkward in some specific situations.

See section 7.14 of the C# 4 spec for more details.

Casting either the second or third operand to the type that you *actually* want for the conditional expression is the way to fix the problem. Note that another situation this often comes up in is nullable types:

```
// Invalid
int? a = SomeCondition ? null : 10;

// All valid
int? a = SomeCondition ? (int?) null : 10;
int? b = SomeCondition ? default(int?) : 10;
int? c = SomeCondition ? null : (int?) 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator cannot determine the resultant type from its components, which may be either `RedirectToRouteResult` or `RedirectResult`. In order to resolve this, you should explicitly cast either (or both) of the components to the base type:

```
ActionResult foo = (someCondition) ? 
                   (ActionResult)RedirectToAction("Foo","Bar") :
                   Redirect(someUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional part tries to resolve itself regardless of the variable it's being assigned to. The compiler gives a warning that it can't determine which class to use as a return value, because RedirectToRouteResult can't be cast the same as RedirectResult, as far as the conditional part is concerned. However if just one side is cast to the base class, the other is implicitly cast as well, so casting the first would be valid:

```
 var foo = (someCondition)? 
                  (ActionResult )RedirectToAction("Foo","Bar") :
                  Redirect(someUrl);
```

but only casting the alternative too:

```
 var foo = (someCondition)? 
    RedirectToAction("Foo","Bar") :
   (ActionResult)Redirect(someUrl);
```