# Why must I cast to (int?) in C# when variable type is [int?]

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone please explain me the *logic reason* why I must cast `null` to `int?`

When the left argument  type can have their both types ?

Insted of doing

```
  int? k = (DateTime.Now.Ticks%5 > 3 ? 1 : null);
```

I must do

```
  int? k = (DateTime.Now.Ticks%5 > 3 ? 1 : (int?) null);
```

although `int? k = null` is perfectly valid.

**An opposite example :**

I didn't have to do it in:

`string k = (DateTime.Now.Ticks%5 > 3 ? "lala" : null);`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964065/conditional-operator-doesnt-work-with-two-types-that-inherit-the-same-base-type/10964093#10964093 - not an exact duplicate, but close.

Comment: Or see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330471/c-sharp-why-cant-a-nullable-int-be-assigned-null-as-a-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330471/c-sharp-why-cant-a-nullable-int-be-assigned-null-as-a-value)

Comment: @JonSkeet _The type of the conditional expression has to be either the type of the second operand or the type of the third operand_ in the first example of mine it cant find a common type. ok. but in my last sample , what is the common type ? string ? null could be anything

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The type is `string` - `null` can be converted to `string`, whereas it *can't* be converted to `int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int? k = (DateTime.Now.Ticks%5 > 3 ? 1 : (int?) null);
```

In this case what we have is 1 is `int` and `null` is actually `null`
Now the confusion is the ternary operator is confused as what is the return type `int` or well `null` and since its `int` it won't accept `null`

So you would need to cast it to a nullable `int`

Now in the other case you have a string and null is perfectly acceptable for a `string`

Further explanation can be found at [Type inference - Eric](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx)

> The second and third operands of the ?: operator control the type of
>   the conditional expression. Let X and Y be the types of the second and
>   third operands. Then,
>
> - If X and Y are the same type, then this is the type of the    conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, if an implicit conversion exists from X to Y, but not from    Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, if an implicit conversion exists from Y to X, but not from    X to Y, then X is the type of the conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time    error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler doesn't use the type of the variable in the left hand side to determine the type of the expression on the right hand side. First it determines what type the expression is, then it determines if it's possible to put it in the variable.

There is no type close enough that is common between an `int` and a `null` value. You have to either make the `int` value nullable or the `null` value "intable" for the compiler to find a common ground for the values.

When you have a `string` and a `null` value the compiler can simply use one of the types, because a string is already nullable.