# Conditional operator with covariance

Tags: c#, covariance, conditional-operator

This code doesn't compile. Am I wrong to expect it to?

```
interface I{};
class A : I{};
class B : I{};
I mything = someBoolCondition ? new A : new B;
```

The problem being that the compiler says it is unable to determine the return type of the conditional operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964065/conditional-operator-doesnt-work-with-two-types-that-inherit-the-same-base-type or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087304/the-c-sharp-conditional-operator-gets-confused-but-why

Comment: Try `I mything = someBoolCondition ? new A() as I : new B() as I;`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will only consider the types of the 2 operands and implicit conversions between them. It will not look for base types or implemented interfaces.

You will need to explicitly cast one of the operands to `I`.

From [C# language specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> The second and third operands, x and y, of the ?: operator control the type of the conditional expression.
>
> • If x has type X and y has type Y then
>
> o  If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> o If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from Y to X, but not from X to Y, then X is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> o Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

If the compiler checked base types too, any combination of types would be valid - in the worse case, the result type would be `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast one of the operands to `I`. Like this :

```
I mything = someBoolCondition  ?  (I) new A() : new B();
```